# How to create a dataframe with different number of values?

Tags: r

When I create a dataframe I do:

```
dt = data.frame(a=c(1:5),b=c(1:20))
dt
   a  b
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
5  5  5
6  1  6
7  2  7
8  3  8
9  4  9
10 5 10
11 1 11
12 2 12
13 3 13
14 4 14
15 5 15
16 1 16
17 2 17
18 3 18
19 4 19
20 5 20
```

as you can see the value of the first column (`a`) are repeated.
How can I create different "columns" with different number of values?

Thanks
H

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `list`. A `data.frame` is a special kind of list in which all elements are of the same length.

```
list(a=c(1:5),b=c(1:20))
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: can I add a vector in the list if I have already created the list() ? example, with the list in your example, can I add column c in a different line of code?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `c` function to combine lists. eg, Assume you called the above `l1`, then use `c(l1,list(c=1:3))`